# Parsing individual elements of a JSON array

Tags: android, json

I want to parse a json array and get its individual elements in android. I have my json file in asset folder. This is type of my json:

```
{
   "name":"hello",
   "data":[1,2,3,4]
}
```

I want to get the elements of "data" key such as "1","2","3",& "4" so that I can add it to an array list.The file name is gaitData.json. I tried this method but its not able to read individual elements of array "data". Please help!!

```
     InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("gaitdata.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json=new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray hip_min=object.getJSONArray("hip_min");
```

After this step I iterate the hip_min array using for loop but that does not work either.

Comment: Are you you looking to learn the specifics of JSON or just want to parse it as quick as possible? If the latter I would recommend: https://github.com/square/moshi

Comment: Just want to parse it quickly !! Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get array values like this,

```
String jsonString = getAssetJsonData("gaitdata.json");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
    if (jsonArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                String str = (String) jsonArray.get(i).getValue();
                list.add(str);
            }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is getAssetJsonData() method,

```
public String getAssetJsonData(String fileName) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open(fileName);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
       }

        Log.e("data", json);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: but  'jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data"); ' will give me the entire array is it? How will I access the elements within it. Shall I use again get method.

Comment: also it tell me handle exception for the first code you type and when I do so it does not read the data.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Finally now I am able to parse the data using json. Thumbs up for you!!.